If a group is a finite extension of a finite rank group does it have finite rank itself
If $H$ is a subgroup of $G, H$ has finite rank r and $|G:H|=n$ finite, how can I prove that $G$ has finite rank?
I can say that any finitely generated subgroup $K$ of $G$ is included in a subgroup generated by at most $r+n$ elements, but what can i say about the subgroup $K$ itself?

What definition of the rank of a group are you using? Anyway, I expect that the fact that $|K:K \cap H| \le n$ is relevant,

rank is r means every finitely generated subgroup can be generated by r elements and at least one can't be generated by r-1.

OK, so $K \cap H$ can be generated by at moxt $r$ elements, and hence $K$ can be generated by at  most $r+n$ elements.

of course! i was using G and  H rather than K and K∩H, and i was getting a bigger subgroup than K.
